# EnvelopeCenter EF and spatial types

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am using EF with spatial types. I have a field (polygon) of type DbGeography. I need it on a google map and need the center of the polygon. How is this achived with EF?

```
 using (DB dbCtx = new DB(Config.ConnectionString))
        {
            var test = dbCtx.SiteList.ToList();
            var tt = test.First().Polygon....?
        }
```

Comment: I don't know a lot about EF (DBA here), but the geography type provides an EnvelopeCenter method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlspatialfunctions.envelopecenter(v=vs.113).aspx might be of help.

Comment: I got that and ended up creating a view with a center column based on envelope center. But retrieving that with EF is apperently a science. But I will ask a new question about that. It is kind of strange that this is not straight forward I would expect that this is made for working with maps.

Comment: I agree. Especially since the spatial types in SQL Server are implemented in CLR. So it should be trivial to expose those methods in .NET/EF.